# How to cut out holes nicely, without applying subsurf modifier (in the correct topology order)

Tags: modeling, modifiers

Basically, this is what I want, *without* applying any of my modifiers. I assume I just need to put the modifiers in the right order? I'm sorry if the video is in bad quality, but I used the screencast option in Blender, then used FormatFactory (free software) to convert it to an animated GIF.

[GIF animation of problem](https://6frmpw-bn1305.files.1drv.com/y3mL6US2WJbq7g2WtgS3JMfR7YktD43-qiTP-2JMNKTslQGMrwWRd9JYX2lx_9xINN-bYX0v2QpYNMg0jA-NJEo0HHxOm28x0R6f-DfiJPizZu41KV0o28O6eymZbHhe0om1Ie-XpPLPttxbPWlo7a6Frn5iZR-EI2dkN_-CML4u_0/0001-0030.gif?psid=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I would approach this is:
Make the cylinders with as few sides as possible. then add the boolean modifier before the subsurf. And apply it.

Additionally, you should move your surrounding geometry so that it "encompasses" the 3 holes. That way, when you apply the modifier, all the weird lines are going to be in the small space surrounding the holes.
If you can't change your geometry, then try adding a loop cut to do the same thing.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Basically, this is what I need. But It only seems to work when the modifiers are applied from top to bottom, like shown in this image https://1drv.ms/i/s!Aor67FEekLdyhJVcq_3x0onW93DqsQ

Comment: I would apply the subsurf last